# How to fetch the correct date from UNIX timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, mktime

I'm taking two dates from form into `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Now I'm converting these two dates into equivalent UNIX timestamp value and create a SQL query to fetch the records from the database falling into this range. The small code snippett for this is as given below :

```
if($request['from_date']!='' && $request['to_date']!='') {
            $from_date  = clean($request['from_date']);
            $to_date    = clean($request['to_date']);       

            list($fd, $fm, $fy) = explode('/', $from_date);
            list($td, $tm, $ty) = explode('/', $to_date);

            $mk_from_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $fm, $fd, $fy);
            $mk_to_time   = mktime(0, 0, 0, $tm, $td, $ty);
$date_range = " ( user_reg_date BETWEEN ".$mk_from_time." AND ".$mk_to_time." ) ";
}
```

The properly formatted query gets generated with some other code and gives me the result. But my issue is when I enter two dates viz. `01/07/2013 and 31/07/2013` and fetch the records from DB then it is actually giving the records `from date 01/07/2013 to date 30/07/2013`. Actually it is expected to give the records till `31/07/2013`. If I put to date as `01/08/2013` then it is returning the records till `31/07/2013` as per my requirement. Means in short `to date` is lagging behind by one day. Can any one help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance. One more important thing is the field `user_reg_date` in DB contains all values in UNIX Timestamp format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$mk_to_time   = mktime(23, 59, 59, $tm, $td, $ty);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you explain me where should I use your code snippett. In from date or to date or both.

Comment: You have a line `$mk_to_time   = mktime(0, 0, 0, $tm, $td, $ty);` Change it to `$mk_to_time = mktime(23, 59, 59, $tm, $td, $ty);`

Comment: I changed the line as you stated, but still it is lagging behind by 5 and half hours. Means if I give a date as 31/07/2013 and convert it into User readable format it is giving Wed, 31 Jul 2013 18:29:59 GMT. Means it is stil lagging behind by 5 and half hours. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Look in your `php.ini` file. Change `date.timezone =` to a valid timezone for your site. I am guessing you have a default possibly UTC but you dont run the site in the UTC timezone. Look here for a valid timezone for where you are `http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php`